# REST Resource route naming for get and ResourceByID and ResourceByName

Tags: rest

I am trying to write 2 Rest GET methods.

1. Get user by *Id*
2. Get user by *userName*.

I need to know if there is any resource naming convention for this. Both my *id* and *username* are strings.

I came up with:

1. `/api/{v}/users/{userid}`
2. `/api/{v}/users/username/{username}`

However, 2) doesn't seem correct and if I change 2) to `/api/{v}/users/{username}`, I am mapping to 1) as both id and username are strings. Or is it considered acceptable to use `/api/{v}/userbyName/{username}`?

How should I name my resource route in case 2) ?

Comment: Do you need any additional input/help? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: https://vimeo.com/17785736 (15 minutes which will solve all your questions)

And **what is unique**? Is the username unique or only the id or both are unique?

There is a simple rule for all that:

```
/collection/item
```

> However, 2) doesn't seem correct and if I change 2) to /api/{v}/users/{username}, I am mapping to 1) as both id and username are strings.

If your item can be identified with an `id` and also with an `unique username` -  it doesn't matter if it's the username or the id - simply look for both (of course your backend needs to handle that) and retrieve it.

According to your needs this would be correct:

`/api/{v}/users/{userid}`

`/api/{v}/users/{username}`

but I would choose only to use: `/api/{v}/users/{userid}` and filter by username only with a query parameter (description for that down there below)

> Also will I break any rules if I come up with
>   /api/{v}/userbyName/{username}

**Yes** - `/api/{v}/userbyName/{username}` will **break** the rule about `/collection/item` because userByName is clearly not a collection it would be a function - but with a real restful thinking api there is no function in the path.

---

*Another way* to get the user by name would be using a filter/query paramter - so the ID will be available for the PathParameter and the username only as filter. which than would look like this:

`/api/{v}/users/?username={username}`

This also don't break any rules - because the query parameter simply filters the whole collection and retrieves only the one where username = username.

---

> How should I name my resource route in case 2) ?

Your 2) will break a rule - so I can't/won't suggest you a way to do it like this.

---

Have a look at this: https://vimeo.com/17785736 this simple presentation will help you a lot about understanding rest.

[image]

---

**Why would you go this way?**

Ever had a look at a *javascript framework* like - let's say **ember**. ([Ember Rest-Adapter](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/the-rest-adapter/)). If you follow the idea described up there and maybe also have a look at the json format used by ember and their rest adapter - you can make your frontend developer speed up their process and save a lot of money + time.

Comment: glad to help :) if there is have any question open - comment and I'm sure we find a answer - or maybe create a new one and pass me the link to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

By REST you send back links, which can contain URI templates. For example: `/api/{v}/users/{userid}` in your case, where `v` and `userid` are template variables. Since the URI structure does not matter from a client perspective you can use whatever structure you want. Ofc. it is more convenient to use nice and short URIs, because it is easier to write the routing with them.

According to the URI standard the path contains the hierarchical while the query contains the non-hierarchical part of the URI, but this is just a loose constraint, in practice ppl use both one.

- `/api/{v}/users/name/{username}`
- `/api/{v}/users/name:{username}`
- `/api/{v}/users?name="{username}"`

---

Ofc. you can use a custom convention, for example I use the following:

- I don't use plural resource name by collections
- I end collection path with slash
- I use slash by reducing a collection to sub-collections or individual items
- I don't use slash to give the value of a variable in the path, I use colon instead
- I use as few variables and as short URI as I can
- I use query by reducing a collection to sub-collections especially by defining complex filters with logical operators

So in you case my solution would be

- `/api/{v}/user/`
- `/api/{v}/user/name:{username}`
- `/api/{v}/user/{userid}`

and

- `/api/{v}/user/?firstName="John"`
- `/api/{v}/user/?firstName="John|Susan"&birthYear="1980-2005"`

or

- `/api/{v}/user/firstName:John/`
- `/api/{v}/user/firstName:John|Susan/birthYear:1980-2005/`

etc...

But that's just my own set of constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Each resource should have a unique URI.

```
GET /users/7
{
    "id": 7,
    "username": "jsmith",
    "country": "USA"
}
```

Finding the user(s) that satisfy a certain predicate should be done with query parameters.

```
GET /users?username=jsmith
[
    "/users/7"
]
```